# Rxjava with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I using rxjava 2 in kotlin but it is not compiling how should i resolve it ?

```
var emailField = name.textChanges().skipInitialValue().toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
var passField = password.textChanges().skipInitialValue().toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)

Flowable.combineLatest(emailField,passField, BiFunction { t1, t2 ->  t1.isNotEmpty() && t2.isNotEmpty()    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was missing generic params for combineLatest

```
 BiFunction<T1, T2, R> { t1, t2 -> combineFunction(t1,t2) }
```